# Visualising multiple data sets containing progressive elements using R

Tags: r, data-visualization, barplot

I have two datasets which I will like to visualise together. I'm not sure the best way to visualise the data. I have tried barchart in R which didn't work due to the nature of the datasets.

early_data:

```
id  prob    type
1   0.03    0
2   0.34    0
3   0.28    0
4   0.65    1
5   0.52    1
6   0.29    1
```

late_data:

```
id  prob    type
1   0.07    0
2   0.52    1
3   0.28    0
4   0.66    1
5   0.82    1
6   0.53    1
```

What I want to see is a joint visualisation "early_data" and "late_data" such that differences in their "prob" variables are clear (prob" variable higher in "early_data" than "late_data"). I also want to highlight the "type" variable (e.g., by color). Does anyone know a solution for this problem using R base or any other approach?

Comment: How many (pairs of) data points do you have? Six are simple to visualize, sixty starts to get crowded, for six hundred or six thousand you need start compressing information.

Comment: There are 350 pairs of data for each of "early_data" and "late_data".  Thanks